# How to get a node value with XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xmlpullparser

Im trying to get values from an XML with the XmlPullParser but can't reach the values I want.
The XML-structure is similar to the Android Strings.xml:

```
<string name="value"> 1 </string>
```

I can get "string", "name" & "value" from the XML but can't reach the actual value "1". It seems like the XmlPullParser only works for structures like this:

```
<value> 1 </value>
```

Do I need to use another parser or is there a way to reach "1" (the value above) in some way?

Thanks!

Comment: I had the opposit problem, couldn't get name and value ;) figured it out though getAttributeValue() was what I searched for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you checked the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) of the XmlPullParser? It has an example how to use it.
Basically you can get the value inside the tags by calling `getText` when the parser reaches correct position when you're calling `next`.

Comment: Im embarrased, that was actually all I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

`nextText()` method will do the trick

Comment: this is the actual answer..!!

Answer (score 1):

To extend the previous answers with a code snippet of how to actually use this.

```
/* initialization skipped */
eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                    Log.d("Task2/Parser","Start document");
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    Log.d("Task2/Parser", "Start tag "+xpp.getName());
                    if (xpp.getName().equals("temperature")){
                        temperature = Double.parseDouble(xpp.nextText());
                        return temperature;
                    }
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    Log.d("Task2/Parser", "End tag "+xpp.getName());
                } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    Log.d("Task2/Parser", "Text "+xpp.getText());
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
```

This code returns the value within the xml tag `<temperature>` as a double. Obviously, it would need more error handling, but just so other people ending up here can get it with less googling.